# Laravel MySql join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel 5 application.
I have issue getting results from two database table. here is what i have:

```
table A: 'courses' 

id   |    Course
————————————————
1    |    Math
2    |    History
3    |    Geography
4    |    Computer
```

and Table B

```
user_id | classroom_id | course 
1       | 5            | 3
1       | 5            | 4
1       | 6            | 2
```

I returned the table A on a for each loop but I would like to check what courses the user_id 1 has to return true or false on every column on the for-each loop.
Something like this:

Returned item for user_id 1:

```
id   |    course     |  status
____________________________
1    |    Math       | false
2    |    History    | true
3    |    Geography  | true
4    |    Computer   | true
```

This is I have:

```
$AllList = DB::table('users')
            ->join('courses', 'users.id', '=', 'courses.parent_id')
            ->join('classroom', 'users.id', '=', 'classroom.user_id')->where('classroom_id', '=', 5)       
            ->get();
```

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: A left join should do it, if empty then it's 'false'

Comment: @ka_lin Thanks for comment but what the code should be?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: first you have to create a belongs to relation,then when you query "courses" just check is there any relation with table b then print rather true or false.Please show here what you tried,that we can help you through code or logic

Comment: `select course from A inner join B on A.id=B.couse where B.user_id=1;`

Comment: @ka_lin I have updated the question with my code..

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `join` with `leftJoin`:

```
$AllList = DB::table('courses')
            ->select('courses.id','course.name')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'courses.parent_id')
            ->join('classroom', 'users.id', '=', 'classroom.user_id')->where('classroom_id', '=', 5)       
            ->get();
```

`Course` field will be `NULL` thus empty string if there is no match

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how to limit the returned columns?because I have all columns on both tables.

Comment: Just add `->select([column names as array]);` like I did above

Comment: Cool, Thanks. I just voted up you answer and not selecting as the accepted answer to get more answer form other people. Thanks again

Comment: the reason why didn't choose as the answer because I still get Null for all the Data:  [{"id":null,"name":null},{"id":null,"name":null},{"id":null,"name":null},{"id":null,"name":null}]

Comment: Oh sorry, I replaced '`courses` with `users` because there are users with no courses, that is why you are getting empty values

Answer (score 1):

the below lines of code will help you...

```
    $getCourse = DB::table('courses')->get(['id','course']);

    $getCourse = collect($getCourse)->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray();

    foreach ($getCourse as $key => $value)
    {
        $flag = DB::table('classroom')
                    ->where('user_id',1)
                    ->where('course',$value['id'])
                    ->pluck('id');
        if($flag)
        {
            $getCourse[$key]['status'] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $getCourse[$key]['status'] = false;
        }
    }

    dd($getCourse);
```